# Having an issue with shipping options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

I have a problem fetching the shipping options, the error: 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'options[0].id')'. I have checked everything I can think of to debug this issue. I am using check.io as for my e-commerce backend. I have added different shipping option on that site however they are not showing up. I have a hard time understanding why there is a type error

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  InputLabel,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  Button,
  Grid,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import FormInput from "../CheckoutForm/CustomTxtField";
import { commerce } from "../../lib/Commerce";

const AddressForm = ({ checkoutToken, test }) => {
  const [shippingCountries, setShippingCountries] = useState([]);
  const [shippingCountry, setShippingCountry] = useState("");
  const [shippingSubdivisions, setShippingSubdivisions] = useState([]);
  const [shippingSubdivision, setShippingSubdivision] = useState("");
  const [shippingOptions, setShippingOptions] = useState([]);
  const [shippingOption, setShippingOption] = useState("");
  const methods = useForm();

  const fetchShippingCountries = async (checkoutTokenId) => {
    const { countries } = await commerce.services.localeListShippingCountries(
      checkoutTokenId
    );

    setShippingCountries(countries);
    setShippingCountry(Object.keys(countries)[0]);
  };

  const fetchSubdivisions = async (countryCode) => {
    const { subdivisions } = await commerce.services.localeListSubdivisions(
      countryCode
    );

    setShippingSubdivisions(subdivisions);
    setShippingSubdivision(Object.keys(subdivisions)[0]);
  };

  const fetchShippingOptions = async (
    checkoutTokenId,
    country,
    stateProvince = null
  ) => {
    const options = await commerce.checkout.getShippingOptions(
      checkoutTokenId,
      { country, region: stateProvince }
    );

    setShippingOptions(options);
    setShippingOptions(options[0].id);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkoutToken && checkoutToken.id) {
      fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id);
      console.log(checkoutToken.id);
    }
  }, [checkoutToken]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingCountry) fetchSubdivisions(shippingCountry);
  }, [shippingCountry]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingSubdivision)
      fetchShippingOptions(
        checkoutToken.id,
        shippingCountry,
        shippingSubdivision
      );
  }, [shippingSubdivision]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Shipping address
      </Typography>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form
          onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) =>
            test({
              ...data,
              shippingCountry,
              shippingSubdivision,
              shippingOption,
            })
          )}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <FormInput name="firstName" label="First name" />
            <FormInput name="lastName" label="Last name" />
            <FormInput name="address1" label="Address line 1" />
            <FormInput name="email" label="Email" />
            <FormInput name="city" label="City" />
            <FormInput name="zip" label="Zip / Postal code" />
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Country</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingCountry}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingCountry(e.target.value)}
              >
                {Object.entries(shippingCountries)
                  .map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Subdivision</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingSubdivision}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingSubdivision(e.target.value)}
              >
                {Object.entries(shippingSubdivisions)
                  .map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Options</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingOption}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingOption(e.target.value)}
              >
                {shippingOptions
                  .map((sO) => ({
                    id: sO.id,
                    label: `${sO.description} - (${sO.price.formatted_with_symbol})`,
                  }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <Button component={Link} variant="outlined" to="/cart">
              Back to Cart
            </Button>
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Next
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddressForm;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you check options have some data ?
setShippingOptions(options);
setShippingOptions(options[0].id);

Comment: Using commercejs i have added data and cannot get that data through options and i cannot figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a commercejs.com issue not a coding issue